# PAC CLI Unpack and Pack managed solution

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-365-sales

I am trying to pack the managed solution using PAC CLI for our automated pipeline. I am seeing some peculiar behavior

when we use unpack command it unpacks all the components

`pac solution unpack -z solution.zip -f CustomCode  -p managed -loc -lcid`

This is the folder after extract
[Extracted file view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxCnW.png)

but when we pack the same soultion again the organization setting folder will be removed

`pac solution pack -z solution.zip -f CustomCode  -p managed -loc -lcid`

[after packing the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in8YC.png)